# What tense should I use in the following sentence

Tags: tenses, conditionals

I would like to know what is the appropriate tense in the following sentence.

> An emperor would/will always be an emperor, no matter how badly he botched/botches his job, but a president or a PM will lose his job if he fails to satisfy the majority of the citizenry.

On the one hand, the first part seems to indicate a general rule, thus should use present tense i.e.

> An Emperor will always be an emperor...

but on the other hand, I am trying to comment on an institution that no longer exists, and should use past tense.

Thank you for your time

Comment: You use the past tense because the institution no longer exists. The general rule is not a general rule. It *was* a general rule. Now it is not even a rule anymore.

Comment: Consider King Charles I of England, and King Constantine of Greece, and the Roman Emperor Nero.

Comment: It depends on the "voice" you're using.

Answer (score 1):

As you say

> I am trying to comment on an institution that no longer exists, and should use past tense.

Then use the past tense: would.

An emperor would *(past)* always be an emperor, no matter how badly he botched *(past)* his job, but *[you have now moved to the present]* a president or a PM will lose *(future)* his job if he fails *(present)* to satisfy the majority of the citizenry.

Answer (score 0):

An emperor will always be an emperor, no matter how badly he botches his job, but a president or a PM will lose his job if he fails to satisfy the majority of the citizenry.